# Target binary file level generated documentation in Rust project

Tags: rust, documentation, rustdoc

I have a Rust project consisting of two binary sources sharing the same library:

*Cargo.toml:*

```
<...>

[[bin]]
name = "quoter_xml"
path = "src/quoter_xml.rs"

[[bin]]
name = "quoter"
path = "src/quoter.rs"

<...>
```

*src/quoter_xml.rs:*

```
use <...>

fn main() {
    <...>
}
```

*src/quoter.rs:*

```
use <...>

fn main() {
    <...>
}
```

*src/lib.rs:*

```
pub mod <...>
```

When I compile it, I get two binaries: `quoter_xml` and `quoter_xml`.
When I generate doc using `cargo doc`, I get independent doc files `doc/quoter_xml/index.html` and `doc/quoter/index.html`.

What I want is to add some description texts to the top of these doc files.
I've tried to add "//!"-type comments to binary sources, for example:

*src/quoter_xml.rs:*

```
use <...>

//! quoter_xml - this binary is for <..>

fn main() {
    <...>
}
```

But if I compile project after it, I get an error:

```
error[E0753]: expected outer doc comment
  --> src/quoter_xml.rs:10:1
   |
10 | //! quoter_xml - this binary is for <..>
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: inner doc comments like this (starting with `//!` or `/*!`) can only appear before items
help: you might have meant to write a regular comment
   |
10 - //! quoter_xml - this binary is for <..>
10 + // quoter_xml - this binary is for <..>
   |
```

Compiler consider to use regular comments, but I don't want it: I need comments that will get to the top of doc pages, "//!"-type comments.

I've search Internet and found recommendation to place these type of comments in `src/lib.rs` file, but this is not what I want. I want to have independent top-level comments in doc for each binary file.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you simply need to move your comment above the `use` statement in quoter_xml.rs.

```rust
//! quoter_xml - this binary is for <..>

use <...>

// Crate level doc comment cannot be after any code.

fn main() {
    <...>
}
```